# Objective-C memory management: BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-management

I'm working on a bible iPhone app. Here are the basics of what I'm doing so far:

- My XMLParser parses an xml file and creates a Bible object
- Specifically, the xml is stored in each Chapter object.
- Once parsing is done, the viewController grabs a Chapter from the Bible and displays its innerHtml in a UIWebview.

This works, but whenever I try to access the Bible object outside of -(void)viewDidLoad; it either gives me a BAD_ACCESS error, or the results for what I'm asking for is unreadable. I think this is a memory management problem..

**Here's what I'm doing in the viewController**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Create parser and XML data object.
    //Then, parse that data

    finalBible = [[Bible alloc]init]; 

    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"KJV" ofType:@"html"];
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    //INT I WANTED TO USE TO ITERATE WHEN BUTTON WAS PRESSED TO ADVANCE TO NXT CHAPTER
    chapToShow = 2;

    parser = [[XMLParser alloc] init];
    nsParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:myData];

    //set delegate for NSXMLParser
    [nsParser setDelegate:parser];

    //PARSE THE XML FILE AND BUILD BIBLE OBJECT - PARSED OK!!
    if ([nsParser parse]) {
        NSLog(@"Parsed with no errors!! :)");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Error parsing document");
    }

    //IT SEEMS MY PROBLEMS MAY BE IN THIS TRADE OFF.
    //I WANT TO STORE THE PARSER'S BIBLE IN THIS NEW BIBLE OBJECT.
    finalBible = [parser getBible];

    //Test querying bible via pullVerse method - IT WORKS!!
    NSLog(@"%@",[finalBible pullVerse:@"65.021.000"]);


    NSString *firstChap = [[[[finalBible getTestament:0]getBook:@"Genesis"]getChapterWithInt:3]getInnerHtml];

    //Try and load Genesis 1 - THIS WORKS!!
    NSLog(@"...Loading Genesis 1...");
    [bibleView loadHTMLString:firstChap baseURL:nil];

    //LOADING THE VERSION WORKS HERE!!
    NSLog(@"Version = %@", [finalBible getVersion]);

}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Now reading chapter %d", chapToShow);

    //HERE I'M TRYING TO GET THE BIBLE VERSION BUT THE APP CRASHES AS A RESULT
    NSLog(@"Testing the bible: Version = %@ \n OK", [finalBible getVersion]);

    //NOTE: I've even tried [[parser getBible] getVersion] and it still doesn't work.
    // I don't release the parser till the view's dealloc method, so I'm not sure why I            
    // can't access it here...

}
```

Of course, I'd be happy to post any other code. I just didn't want to over-stuff the page with code, so I pasted only where I think the problem lies, or at least where it's occurring.

Comment: Is there really a need for another bible app? http://www.google.de/search?q=site:itunes.apple.com+bible

Comment: yea, i know there are a lot out there. I should have been more specific, it's actually a memory verse app. There are fewer of those, and the ones that are in the app store seem to be quite old and non-aestetically pleasing. I'm building a bible reader inside the app to make it easy for users to search for and pick a verse they want.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I added NSLog messages in the dealloc methods to see if anything was being released when it wasn't supposed to be.... but none were called, so I'm assuming all the objects are still active.

Answer (score 4):

You allocate finalBible, but then you set `finalBible = [parser getBible]` so the previous allocation is pointless. Also, it appears as though `[parser getBible]` returns an autoreleased object, so you should call `[[parser getBible] retain]` to make sure it does not leave memory.

Comment: I tried getting rid of the finalBible memory allocation. I also tried retaining the bible from the parser, but its still a no go. It's definitely weird that finalBible seems to be pointing successfully all the way until buttionPressed;

Comment: What happens if you check the retain count on the finalBible after `[parser getBible]` and in the buttonPressed method?

Comment: it looks like at the end of viewDidLoad the finalBible retainCount is 2. It looks like its still 2 at the beginning of buttonPressed. Just to be sure I'm checking this right.. I set a breakpoint at both places and used the gdb command "call (int)[finalBible retainCount]". It gave me "$1 = 2" the first time and "$2 = 2" during the second call in buttonPressed.

Comment: just so you know, I deleted the allocation for finalBible at the top and added "[[parser getBible]retain];" right before "finalBible = [parser getBible]

Comment: Oh, sorry I meant you to do `finalBible = [[parser getBible] retain]`

Comment: I'm not sure why, but even with this change, I'm still getting a BAD_ACCESS error outside the viewDidLoad method.

Comment: What is [parser getBible] returning? I assume getBible is a method you created yourself.

Comment: the xmlparser has a Bible in it. as its parsing, Books/Chapters/Verses are added to that bible. The getBible method simply returns that Bible. In xmlparser, the bible is declare as a property, initialized in the init method, built, and released in the dealloc method.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what you need to do in your .h file add this line:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) Bible finalBible;
```

Then in your .m file add this line at the top:

```
//This generates the methods (get, set) for your instance variable
@synthesize finalBible;
```

Then drop this line:

```
finalBible = [[Bible] alloc]init];
```

This is because if you keep it, there will be a memory leak right here:

```
finalBible = [parser getBible];
```

Because now you are pointing to a new memory location, and the previous memory location had an object with a retain count of 1 provided by alloc init, and since there will no longer be any reference to this object it will never be released causing a memory leak.

Although if you use this line:

```
self.finalBible = [parser getBible];
```

Because that uses the setter, a setter releases the previous value and retains the new one, so there would not be a memory leak, but it would still be pointless to allocate that object.

Since getBible does not have the `new, alloc or init` keyword it should return an `autoreleased` object, which is why the object is released in the next run loop (not guaranteed but most likely), which is why you cannot access it outside of the `viewDidload()` method.

Comment: hi Oscar, I tried ur suggestions and the problem seems to persist. I noticed you used the term "ivar". I'm not sure what that is.

Comment: Are you suggesting I change my getBible method? Or should I add new, alloc, or init to [parser getBible]?

Comment: @Don Adams Ivar stands for instance variable, also eliminate this line  finalBible = [[Bible alloc]init];, since it is useless because you are reassigning with your parser, and will cause a memory leak too. Instance variable are declared as properties (nonatomic, retain) for example if yours is NOT retain, then self. will not work, you can either declare your property as retain or send the retain message.

Comment: @Don Adams just updated my answer with everything you need to get it working, hope that helps.

Comment: gotcha, I went ahead and deleted it. finalBible is a bible I declared in the .h file so I would be able to access it anywhere in my .m file. would that cause a problem? I also set it as a @property(non atomic, retain)

Comment: @Don Adams You still need that declaration, don't delete it, just add the @ property.

Comment: the declaration I got rid of was `finalBible = [[Bible alloc]init];` at the top. I can put it back, if it do I'll have `self.finalBible = [[parser getBible]retain];` along with it. I already have it set as a property (non atomic, retain) in the .h file.

Comment: @Don Adams oh yes that declaration you need to remove, it should be working now.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this problem by making "finalBible" variable a property of the class using

@property(nonatomic, retain) Bible finalBible; //this is in the .h file
@synthesis finalBible; // at the top of .m file

All the reference to "finalBible" should be made as "self.finalBible"

Comment: hi nan. I actually already have finalBible defined as a property in the .h file. It's also synthesized at the top. I tried calling it with self.finalBible in the buttonPressed method but I still get a BAD_ACCESS error..